# Histogram in Excel with bins

Tags: excel, histogram

I have an excel spreadsheet with score and frequency of scores, as such:

```
Score   Count
0   2297802
1   2392803
2   1258527
3   969550
4   818579
5   675646
6   591326
7   598960
8   506268
9   448232
10  414830
11  382808
...
```

I'm looking for a way to 'bucket' these scores in intervals of (say) 3 and plot them to show the distribution:

```
Score    Count
0-2      5949132
3-5      2463775
...
```

And so on
I'm using Excel for Mac and I tried defining a 3 interval bin in the Analysis ToolPak but that appears to work only on raw data as opposed to the counts that I already have.

Answer (score 0):

- in cells D2 downwards, enter your upper (inclusive) bin limits
- in cell E2, enter `=SUMIF(A:A,"<="&D2,B:B)-SUM(E$1:E1)`
- copy E2 downwards

example result:

[image]